# Element wise matrix multiplication in Theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano, theano-cuda

I could see element wise matrix multiplication using numpy can be done with * operator.

```
print np.mat(np.ones((10,10)))*np.mat(np.ones((10,10)))
```

But couldnt get it working under theano. The code I tried is

```
x = T.dmatrix('x')
y = T.dmatrix('y')
z = x * y
f1 = theano.function([x, y], z)

print f1(np.mat(np.ones((10,10))),np.mat(np.ones((10,10))))
```

Comment: If you just want elementwise multiplication, change `z = x + y` to `z = x * y`.

Comment: @ajcr It s *. + was there by mistake. Corrected

Comment: That code works for me (produces a 10 by 10 array of 1s), what result are you seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I try the following (which is basically your code):

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

import numpy as np

x = T.dmatrix('x')
y = T.dmatrix('y')
z = x * y
f1 = theano.function([x, y], z)

print f1(np.mat(np.ones((10,10))),np.mat(np.ones((10,10))))
```

I get the following:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

So, it works for me.